# Anything needed to allow/give Android Apps access to my Intents?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm creating an Android app and am wondering if there is anything special I need to do to allow other apps access to use a particular Intent from my app for use in theirs?

Also, if Intents are inherently allowed to be used by other apps, is there a way to stop that from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can advertise what your app is capable of via an intent filter.  See [intents and intent filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html).

If you don't add an intent filter to an activity, it can only be started via an explicit intent, so the other app would need to know the full name of your class and invoke it directly.

Comment: If you don't want others to use your defined intents you can add `android:exported="false"` to the manifest entry for the Activity or receiver in question.